# Data em formato fracional estranho 0.00xxxxxxx

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, asp

Recebo essa data vinda do BD:

> 0.002976190476190476

Gostaria de passar para esse formato: `dd/mm/yyyy`, usando `javascript` puro ou `jquery`.

Como eu faço?

---

Aqui é o ASP que monta o select:

```
strsql = ""
                strsql = "select a.cod_operadora, a.nom_operadora, to_char(b.dat_exclusao,'dd/mm/yyyy') dat_exclusao, case when b.dat_exclusao is null then 'N' else 'S' end excluido "
                strsql = strsql & " from ts_odo.odo_operadora             a "
                strsql = strsql & "     ,ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora   b "
                strsql = strsql & "where a.cod_operadora    = b.cod_operadora "
                strsql = strsql & "  and b.cod_prestador_ts = " & cod_prestador_ts
                strsql = strsql & "order by to_number(a.cod_operadora)"                     

                set TopDB = server.CreateObject("TSDB.Data")

                set rsOperadora = TopDB.objrs ( CStr(txt_usuario), _
                                                CStr(txt_senha), _
                                                CStr(txt_ip), _
                                                session("ace_sistema"), _
                                                CStr(txt_modulo), _
                                                strsql)
                set TopDB = nothing
```

E aqui é a chamada ao método js, que está dentro de um while no asp:

```
Response.Write "<script>montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(" & rsOperadora("dat_exclusao") & ")</script>"
```

E essa é a função js que deveria fazer o que eu desejo, imprimir um label a data calculada.

```
function montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(dt_exclusao){

    alert('Paulo: ' + dt_exclusao);

    var arrData = dt_exclusao.split('/');
    var exclusaoFormatada = arrData[1] + '-' + arrData[0] + '-' +  arrData[2];
    var dias = parseInt(prazoSubPrestador);
    var novaData = new Date(arrData[2], arrData[1] - 1, arrData[0]);

    novaData.setDate(novaData.getDate() + dias);

    hoje = new Date(novaData)
    dia = hoje.getDate()
    mes = hoje.getMonth()
    ano = hoje.getFullYear()
    if (dia < 10)
        dia = "0" + dia

    if((mes+1) < 10)
        mes = "0" + (mes+1);

    if (ano < 2000)
        ano = "19" + ano

    var dt = dia + "/" + (mes) + "/"+ano;

    var elem = document.getElementById('ind_exclusao_voluntaria');

    if(elem.value == 'S')
        document.getElementById('lblPrazoSubPrestador').innerHTML = "Prazo de substituição: " + dt;
    else
        document.getElementById('lblPrazoSubPrestador').innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: Primeiro você tem que identificar qual a lógica por trás desse valor numerico que representa a data.

Comment: Não consegui encontrar nada que me retornasse esse número com a lógica UNIX Timestamp, só me retorna 1970. Mas é isso que o @ViniciusDutra disse mesmo, achando a lógica desse número da pra fazer.

Comment: @Ruggi, não tenho idéia de como esse número é formado. Ele é uma data no Oracle. Dei um `to_char(data, 'dd/mm/yyyy')`, mas mesmo assim não funcionou. Esse select está em uma função ASP Clássico. Vou editar o post e postar a função e o select.

Comment: talvez esse valor seja um timestamp do Javascript, mais detalhes neste [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now), caso seja isso mesmo, fica fácil fazer o que você quer:
ficaria assim: 

var data = new Date(valorNumericoDoBanco);
var dataFormatada = (data.getDate() > 9 ? data.getDate() : '0' + data.getDate() ) + '/' + (data.getMonth() > 9 ? data.getMonth() : '0' + data.getMonth() ) + '/' + data.getFullYear();

Comment: Quando eu retirei do asp a tag `<script>`, a data entrou normalmente, mas agora a função javascript não executa mais.

Comment: Assim cara, não entenddo muito de asp em si, mais de Javascript, e parece que o teu Javascript não está errado. Voc~e tentou ver a lógica que o @ViniciusDutra citou?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 2):

O problema pode estar nesse trecho

```
Response.Write "<script>montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(" & rsOperadora("dat_exclusao") & ")</script>"
```

Está passando o parâmetro sem aspas. Como o valor é numérico e contém o caracter matemático de divisão `/`, está acontecendo uma operação matemática no momento que o parâmetro é informado na invocação da função `rsOperadora()`.

Para resolver, informe o parâmetro delimitado por aspas para que seja tratado como string.

Sugestão:

```
Response.Write "<script>montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador('" & rsOperadora("dat_exclusao") & "')</script>"
```

Apenas delimitei com single quote. Isso garante que o valor seja lido como string.

obs: Não sei ao certo é isso mesmo que ocorre pois a informação na pergunta é confusa e vaga.

**Explicação de como cheguei a essa dedução**

Deduzi devido ao formato do valor `0.002976190476190476`. A primeira coisa que imaginei é, como conseguiu fazer uma data chegar a esse formato?

Por dedução lógica imaginei *20/01/2016* (a data de hoje como exemplo). São 20 dividido por 1 que é dividido por 2016, igual a `0.0099206349206349`. Pronto! Temos o formato estranho idêntico ao que postou.

O que torna confuso é que na sua pergunta "afirma" que o valor já vem assim do banco de dados. Mas observando a query de consulta, não fazia sentido. Porém ao observar esse trecho do código `& rsOperadora("dat_exclusao") &`, passou a fazer sentido onde poderia ser o problema.

**Verificando**

Para certificar-se sobre o que deduzi, apenas execute a página ASP normalmente e leia o código HTML gerado no browser. No Chrome, pressione CTRL+U que abrirá uma janela mostrando o código HTML gerado. Procure o trecho `<script>montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(`. Você provavelmente vai ver que a data está correta, algo como `<script>montaDataSubstituicaoPrestador(20/01/2016)</script>`, porém, sem as aspas. Dessa forma, sem aspas, está ocorrendo uma operação matemática. Resultando no valor fracionário.

Comment: Essa foi heroica. :P